# Is there any way to read specific columns of a table in a PDF using C#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

i have a PDf that has a table having 6 columns. I need to extract only the contents of 3 columns in the table. Is this possible using itext sharp?

Comment: Is the table tagged?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with itext sharp directly.You should write somde codes to parse text to html which you read from pdf with itext or any other library.

There are some helpful links here;

https://www.codeproject.com/questions/734458/convert-pdf-to-html-using-csharp-open-source-libra

[c# converting pdf to html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123786/c-sharp-converting-pdf-to-html)

http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.com.tr/2008/08/how-to-convert-pdf-file-to-text-in.html