# Getting bibliographic data from text in a PDF and exporting to a window form

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, metadata, bibliography

I use iText5 for .NET to extract text from a PDF, by using below code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  PdfReader reader2 = new PdfReader("Scharfetter1969.pdf");

  int pagen = reader2.NumberOfPages;
  reader2.Close();

  ITextExtractionStrategy its = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
  for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++)
  {
    textBox1.Text = "";
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("Scharfetter1969.pdf");
    String s = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, its);
    s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(s)));
    textBox1.Text = s;
    reader.Close();
  }
}
```

But I want to get bibliographic data from research paper pdf.

Here is example of data which is extrected from this pdf (in endnote format), Here's [a link](http://lib.semi.ac.cn:8080/tsh/dzzy/wsqk/Nature%20Material/nmat4-42.pdf)!

```
%0 Journal Article
%T Repeated temperature modulation epitaxy for p-type doping and light-emitting diode based on ZnO
%A Tsukazaki, A.
%A Ohtomo, A.
%A Onuma, T.
%A Ohtani, M.
%A Makino, T.
%A Sumiya, M.
%A Ohtani, K.
%A Chichibu, S.F.
%A Fuke, S.
%A Segawa, Y.
%J Nature Materials
%V 4
%N 1
%P 42-46
%@ 1476-1122
%D 2004
%I Nature Publishing Group
```

But remember that this is bibliographic information, it is not available in metadata of this pdf.  I want to access  Article Type (%O), Title (%T), Authors (%A), Date (%D) and (%I) and show it to different assigned textbox in window form.

I am using C# if any one have any code for this, or guide me how to do this.

Comment: You can use String.Split(new[]{'\n'},yourstring) to get array of lines then loop through it and use string.StartsWith() to check is author etc.

Answer (score 3):

PDF is a one-way format. You put data in so that it renders consistently on all devices (monitors, printers, etc) but the format was never intended to pull data back out. Any and all attempts to do that will be pure guess work. iText's `PdfTextExtractor` works but you are going to have to piece things together based on your own arbitrary set of rules, and these rules will probably change from PDF to PDF. The supplied PDF was created by InDesign which does such a great job of making text look good that it actually makes it even harder to parse the data back out.

That said, if your PDFs are all visually consistent, you could try to pull the data out while [retaining formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882098/how-can-i-get-text-formatting-with-itextsharp/6884297#6884297) and use the formatting rules to guess what is what. That post will get you some HTML formatting that you could guess at. *(If this actually works I'd recommend returning something more specific than HTML but I'll leave that up to you.)*

Running it against your supplied PDF shows that the title is using the font `HelveticaNeue-LightExt` at about 17pts so you could write a rule to look for all lines that use that font at that size and combine them together. Authors are done in `HelveticaNeue-Condensed` at about 10pts so that's another rule.

The below code is a modified version of the one linked to above. Its a full working C# 2010 WinForms app targeting iTextSharp 5.1.1.0. It pulls out the title and authors for the supplied PDF but you'll need to tweak it for other PDFs and meta data. See the comments in the code for specific implementation details.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "nmat4-42.pdf"));
            TextWithFontExtractionStategy S = new TextWithFontExtractionStategy();
            string F = iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, 1, S);

            //Buffers to hold various parts from the PDF
            List<string> titles = new List<string>();
            List<string> authors = new List<string>();

            //Array of lines of text
            string[] lines = F.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

            //Temporary string
            string t;

            //Loop through each line in the array
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                //See if the line looks like a "title"
                if (line.Contains("HelveticaNeue-LightExt") && line.Contains("font-size:17.28003"))
                {
                    //Remove the HTML tags
                    titles.Add(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(line, "</?span.*?>", "").Trim());
                }
                    //See if the line looks like an "author"
                else if (line.Contains("HelveticaNeue-Condensed") && line.Contains("font-size:9.995972"))
                {
                    //Remove the HTML tags and trim extra characters
                    t = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(line, "</?span.*?>", "").Trim(new char[] { ' ', ',', '*' });
                    //Make sure we have a valid name, probably need some more exceptions here, too
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t) && t != "AND")
                    {
                        authors.Add(t);
                    }
                }
            }
            //Write out the title to the console
            Console.WriteLine("Title  : {0}", string.Join(" ", titles.ToArray()));
            //Write out each author
            foreach (string author in authors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Author : {0}", author);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(F);

            this.Close();
        }

        public class TextWithFontExtractionStategy : iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.ITextExtractionStrategy
        {
            //HTML buffer
            private StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

            //Store last used properties
            private Vector lastBaseLine;
            private string lastFont;
            private float lastFontSize;

            //http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/parser/TextRenderInfo.html
            private enum TextRenderMode
            {
                FillText = 0,
                StrokeText = 1,
                FillThenStrokeText = 2,
                Invisible = 3,
                FillTextAndAddToPathForClipping = 4,
                StrokeTextAndAddToPathForClipping = 5,
                FillThenStrokeTextAndAddToPathForClipping = 6,
                AddTextToPaddForClipping = 7
            }



            public void RenderText(iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
            {
                string curFont = renderInfo.GetFont().PostscriptFontName;
                //Check if faux bold is used
                if ((renderInfo.GetTextRenderMode() == (int)TextRenderMode.FillThenStrokeText))
                {
                    curFont += "-Bold";
                }

                //This code assumes that if the baseline changes then we're on a newline
                Vector curBaseline = renderInfo.GetBaseline().GetStartPoint();
                Vector topRight = renderInfo.GetAscentLine().GetEndPoint();
                iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(curBaseline[Vector.I1], curBaseline[Vector.I2], topRight[Vector.I1], topRight[Vector.I2]);
                Single curFontSize = rect.Height;

                //See if something has changed, either the baseline, the font or the font size
                if ((this.lastBaseLine == null) || (curBaseline[Vector.I2] != lastBaseLine[Vector.I2]) || (curFontSize != lastFontSize) || (curFont != lastFont))
                {
                    //if we've put down at least one span tag close it
                    if ((this.lastBaseLine != null))
                    {
                        this.result.AppendLine("</span>");
                    }
                    //If the baseline has changed then insert a line break
                    if ((this.lastBaseLine != null) && curBaseline[Vector.I2] != lastBaseLine[Vector.I2])
                    {
                        this.result.AppendLine("<br />");
                    }
                    //Create an HTML tag with appropriate styles
                    this.result.AppendFormat("<span style=\"font-family:{0};font-size:{1}\">", curFont, curFontSize);
                }

                //Append the current text
                this.result.Append(renderInfo.GetText());

                //Set currently used properties
                this.lastBaseLine = curBaseline;
                this.lastFontSize = curFontSize;
                this.lastFont = curFont;
            }

            public string GetResultantText()
            {
                //If we wrote anything then we'll always have a missing closing tag so close it here
                if (result.Length > 0)
                {
                    result.Append("</span>");
                }
                return result.ToString();
            }

            //Not needed
            public void BeginTextBlock() { }
            public void EndTextBlock() { }
            public void RenderImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo) { }
        }
    }
}
```