# How can I read Unicode pdf using itextsharp in c#?

Tags: pdf, unicode, itext

I am working on Unicode [Marathi] based project and for this project my task is to read Unicode text from a PDF in the following fonts

1. CDAC-GISTSurekh
2. CDAC-GISTSurekh+0
3. CDAC-GISTSurekh+1
4. CDAC-GISTSurekh+0 Bold
5. CDAC-GISTSurekh+1 Bold

When I read the PDF using iTextSharp, I get the text as:

```
ररजज - (एस 13) महरररषष
पररप मतदरर जरदद 2014
```

where the actual text should be

```
राज्य - (एस-१३) महाराष्ट्र  प्रारूप मतदार यादी २०१४
```

Please give me solution if anyone have idea about this.

Comment: Your output shows you are already reading "Unicode" (if that failed you would not have seen Marathi). Can you provide a link to a sample PDF with this behavior?

Comment: Please check this is the link for sample pdf.[Click here to view sample pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ezz015t3qdqo5hk/test.pdf)

Comment: This PDF has *exactly* the same problem as described in http://stackoverflow.com/a/15566820/2564301 -- up to and including the same duplicate Unicode code points. This can't be solved by iTextSharp, nor by Acrobat Pro.

Comment: hi, i am also creating pdf using itextsharp, but when pdf is printed with marathi text, some joint word are not printed correctly. for ex- मिरची printed as मरीची , पत्ते printed as पतेते .please give any solution.