# Export to PDF does not support foreign Language

Tags: c#, itext, export-to-pdf

I am doing export to PDF functionality, it works perfect as i want , but it is not supporting gujarati language, Gujarati language data is not getting visible in PDF file.

I am using iTextSharp.dll for export to PDF.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciable.

Comment: It is a common language which is used in "Gujarat" State. Hope you aware with State Gujarat.

Comment: unicode support in itextsharp , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329863/display-unicode-characters-in-converting-html-to-pdf related ?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. (1) Are you exporting to Excel (as per first paragraph) or to PDF (as per question and 2nd paragraph)? (2) In what way is 'it' (iTextSharp?) "not supporting" Gujarati? For instance, does it generate a file but with Gujarati characters incorrectly displayed?

Comment: Some code would be useful.

Comment: This is similar to this, too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15566820/231316