# How to incorporate Telugu language in PDF rendered using iTextSharp with c#?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

How to incorporate Telugu language in pdf? Is there any recommended font from Adobe? Currently I am using Vani.ttf and it is rendering in a different telugu script which is incorrect. Kindly let me know if there is any adobe recommended font for Telugu language. Or kindly let me know an alternative for displaying Telugu language in PDF correctly.

Comment: May this will give some hint http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385270/read-pdf-using-itextsharp-where-pdf-language-is-non-english

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using any version of iText or iTextSharp prior to version 7, you can't produce PDF documents in Telugu. Scripts such as Devanagari and Tamil are only supported since iText 7. iText 7 was introduced at the Great Indian Developer Summit 2016 in Bangalore; see our blog post ["Advanced Typography with iText 7"](http://itextpdf.com/blog/advanced-typography-itext-7).

How to use pdfCalligraph is explained in [Chapter 2 of "iText 7: Building Blocks"](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-2-working-rootelement), but be aware that advanced typography requires a **closed source** add-on called [pdfCalligraph](http://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfcalligraph).

You need the pdfCalligraph module and the license key module. You also need a license key. You can get a [free trial key](http://pages.itextpdf.com/iText-7-Free-Trial-Landing-Page-1.html), but as far as I know, support for Telugu hasn't been implemented yet. We are waiting for a customer who tells us "I need support for Telugu." Once we have such a customer, we'll start implementing it (it could be ready in a couple of weeks).

We decided to make this part of iText closed source to make developers aware of the fact that open source software is software that is completely free. There's always a license. In the case of iText, the open source license is AGPL. The AGPL has some restrictions when used in a commercial context. By making add-on such as pdfCalligraph closed source, we avoid confusion: pdfCalligraph is not free, it's a closed source add-on that can only be used by companies who purchase a commercial license for their use of iText.