# Hindi text is not being displayed when copied from pdf to excel in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: excel, ubuntu, pdf, unicode, utf-8

I installed "*sudo apt-get install ttf-indic-fonts*" and excel could display hindi text copied from Google translate. But when tried copying hindi text from pdf and pasting in excel it got pasted differently as shown below. I tried converting this pdf to excel using various online coversion methods but the problem was the same. Please help.
NOTE:

1. pdf contains tabular data and also contain English at some places.

[image: Hindi text from pdf file]

[image: Copied hindi script from google translate and pdf file]

Comment: Please check whether your pdf is deficient like the one in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385270/read-pdf-using-itextsharp-where-pdf-language-is-non-english) and others in linked questions.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for embedded fonts in the PDF file (Goto File->Properties->Fonts) and found out that one specific font (kruti Dev 10) was not installed . Installed it and now its fine as I am able to display text in hindi. 
Note:Excel file(ods) showed kruti Dev 10 font even before it was installed, but it was actually not.

Answer (score 0):

PDF is likely to have Kritidev/Krutidev font which is actually not a Unicode font. It just shows romanized combinations as Hindi, characters are not actually Unicode Hindi.

Probably there are Kritdev to Unicode converters in the Market.