# extract font color from Pdf using itextsharp

Tags: itext

I want to extract color fom PDF If a text is highlighted with color  extract  and font color from pdf using itextsharp . can anyone proide how to extract color from pdf. 
thanku.

Comment: See this link which should get you started http://stackoverflow.com/q/6882098/231316

Comment: @chris haas. thanku. but i think the code will not give spot colors . can i get the cmyk or rgb value of the text and background color used in pdf.for example  i created a pdf using ms word. where the text contains colors which i need to extract . can i get hexadecimal code of a color or rgb or cmyk color such that which will be easy for me to get color name thanku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int r = renderInfo.GetColorNonStroke().R;
int g = renderInfo.GetColorNonStroke().G;
int b = renderInfo.GetColorNonStroke().B;
```