# Itextsharp get text decoration from pdf

Tags: c#, itext

I am using the iTextSharp library in my project. How can I take PDF line's decoration or style? (something that indicates my text from others.)

```
public static string ReadPdfFile(string fileName)
{
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    if (File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileName);
        pdfReader.GetNamedDestinationFromStrings();
        for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
        {
            ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
            string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy);

            currentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(currentText)));
            text.Append(currentText);
        }
        pdfReader.Close();
    }
    return text.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6884297/231316

Comment: not like this bro. I tried this but i cant did.

Comment: I'm not sure what "i cant did" means. Does the code not do what you want it to do? Does it not compile? Are you looking to extract information about line drawings (rectangles, circles, etc) and not text?

Comment: i used this code and didnt compile. I want like this situation. For example i have a header with 16pt and other characters 10pt. Can i seperate 2 sentences?

Comment: That code was written and tested on iTextSharp 5.1.1. I just tried it again using iTextSharp 5.5.0 and it still compiles and runs just fine. What version of iTextSharp are you targeting and what compiler error message are you getting?