# iTextsharp read text and image from pdf

Tags: itext

We have pdf files which have mixed data of text and images. We can get text and images separately but how we can get text and image with same exact format on pdf file? like 3 line of text and then image and again text etc...

Comment: Depending on how you are extracting images and text you should have access to X,Y coordinates along with other characteristics like width, height, font size and transformation matrices. You'll need to implement your own custom logic to get "order" out of things and define what "before and after" mean. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6884297/231316) for a very basic start.

Comment: I think its very much complex. any way thanks to reply.