# Java iText - Get Font size and family of a text selected from a pdf file

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm writing to inquire a bout a problem when I'm using iText library to extract text contents from PDF file.I would able to extract all the text, but couldn't find the method to extract font styles.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to read the answer to this question: [how can i get text formatting with iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882098/how-can-i-get-text-formatting-with-itextsharp)

In this question, you'll discover that the `TextRenderInfo` has a `getFont()` method that allows you to get the PostScriptFontName. If you are in luck, this PostScriptFontName will give you information about the style.

Note that this won't always work. Please read the answer to this question: [What are the ways of checking if piece of text in PDF documernt is bold using iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065269/what-are-the-ways-of-checking-if-piece-of-text-in-pdf-documernt-is-bold-using-it)

That question shows an example of a font that doesn't reveal anything about its style.

Answer (score 1):

To get the fontsize of a font in itext, use this code:

```
renderInfo.getAscentLine().getStartPoint().get(1)-
renderInfo.getDescentLine().getStartPoint().get(1)
```

This will give you the exact fontsize.