# ITextSharp, ITextExtractionStrategy Extract the Color (Pantone,CMYK)

Tags: c#, itext, cmyk

I Would like to extract the extract Pantone Color from an PDF by using ITextSharp.

My code was taken from Chris Haas [awnser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882098/how-can-i-get-text-formatting-with-itextsharp). It was heavily modified to extract Words with position for it ( not just Chunks ) but still the same in its core. 
Now i have to extract more then the RGB values like the CMYK values or the Pantone Colors, stored inside the PDF.

```
public void RenderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
{
     var colorSupported = renderInfo.GetFillColor();
     ...
}
```

or

```
renderInfo.GetStrokeColor();
```

does not fit my needs. I would like to extract More then RGB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you say

> `renderInfo.GetFillColor()` or `renderInfo.GetStrokeColor()` does not fit my needs. I would like to extract More then RGB.

because those methode return a `BaseColor` which indeed only offers RGB values.

If you inspect the type hierarchy more exactly, though, you will notice that there are multiple classes derived from `BaseColor`, namely `CMYKColor`, `DeviceNColor`, `GrayColor`, `LabColor`, `PatternColor`, `ShadingColor`, `SpotColor`, `UncoloredPattern`, and maybe even more.

You have to identify the actual class of the returned color object and cast accordingly.