# Right to left Text Direction iTextSharp.text.Document

Tags: asp.net, itext

Can I make a document in `RUN_DIRECTION_RTL` when using `iTextSharp.text.Document` to Export RTf Document?

I made it before but using pdf not rtf as:

```
PdfWriter writer = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc,Page.Response.OutputStream);   
writer.RunDirection = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL;
```

Comment: RTL is only for PDF.

Comment: thx dear but is there any alternative solution to do it using rtf??

Comment: Not with itextsharp, besides, rtf was removed from itextsharp in 2009.

Comment: there any alternative solution with any dll?? or to convert this pdf file to rtf file?

Comment: One alternative is to try to extract the text with formatting and create your own RTF document. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6884297/231316) from a long time ago for a very basic start on the text with formatting part.

Comment: iTextSharp has been depreciated and replaced with [iText7](https://itextpdf.com/en/products/itext-7) which is offered under an [AGPL license](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.html) or a paid license for closed source commercial use. They also have an add-on called [pdfCalligraph](https://itextpdf.com/en/products/itext-7/pdfcalligraph) which offers extended support for RTL languages.